# Convert column of dates to count of days from start day

Tags: python, pandas

Simple question but I am struggling to find the answer. I am after a simple count of days from the start date. Thanks in advance.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2015, 2015],
                   'month': [2, 2, 2],
                   'day': [4, 5, 10]})
pd.to_datetime(df)

output

0   2015-02-04
1   2015-02-05
2   2015-02-10
```

What I want

```
    Date        Days_from_start
0   2015-02-04  0
1   2015-02-05  1
2   2015-02-10  6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a timedelta by subtracting the reference, then access the days with [`dt.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
out = pd.to_datetime(df).to_frame('Date')
out['Days_from_start'] = out['Date'].sub(out['Date'].iloc[0]).dt.days

# or if you want from the oldest day
out['Days_from_start'] = out['Date'].sub(out['Date'].min()).dt.days
```

Output:

```
        Date  Days_from_start
0 2015-02-04                0
1 2015-02-05                1
2 2015-02-10                6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can substract and divide like this:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df)

out = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': dates,
    'Days_from_start': dates.sub(dates.iloc[0])//(pd.Timedelta('1D'))
})
```

Output:

```
        Date  Days_from_start
0 2015-02-04                0
1 2015-02-05                1
2 2015-02-10                6
```

Answer (score 0):

`diff()` and `cumsum()` can be used

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df)
s.to_frame('date').assign(days_from_start = s.diff().dt.days.fillna(0).cumsum())
```

Output:

```
        date  days_from_start
0 2015-02-04              0.0
1 2015-02-05              1.0
2 2015-02-10              6.0
```